# ACM SIGCOMM 2015 LaTeX template not Compiling

Tags: templates, acm

I downloaded the ACM Sigcomm 2015 template but its not compiling and giving me hundreds of errors. Kindly help me.
Here is the template link: http://conferences.sigcomm.org/sigcomm/2015/doc/sig-alternate-10pt.cls

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that this template is a CLASS file *.cls so you need to add it in your *.tex document as:

```
\documentclass[conference]{sig-alternate}
```

where sig-alternate is the required *.cls file that needs to be in the working directory of your project. You can create this class file sig-alternate.cls by copying the code from the link: http://conferences.sigcomm.org/sigcomm/2015/doc/sig-alternate-10pt.cls and pasting it in any text editor and saving it as *.cls. I hope you got my point.